# How to create resource file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I use ASP.NET Core. I want to "embbed" text file into application and use it during seeding DataContext only. I don't want anyone to access this file.

Comment: You mean that you don't want to have this file in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you don't put this text file into the wwwroot folder and don't use the [Directory browsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#directory-browsing) for the whole application, that means no one could access the root path' file.

If you still don't want to let anyone access it trough the http or https. You could write a custom middleware to check the request path, if this path contains the .txt, you could return the access denied response.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) => {

                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".txt"))
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
  $"Acess Denied");
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }

   
            } );
```

Result:

[image]